# Programming language and database concurrent locking primitives

Tags: database, concurrency

I am writing an article about both programming language locking primitives (which are really wrappers for OS primitives) and database locking primitives. Are there any short wide-spread titles for these two types of locking? For example, "code locking" and "database locking"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is commonly referred to as locking; regardless of the implementation.

The database does have variations of locking in the form of pessimistic and optimistic locking; however the proper verbiage is still locking.

You can talk about which layer in an N tier architecture the locking is taking place at but there is no naming formality other then the formalities that exist within a typical N tier discussion.

An example would be that all locking at an application level will take place at the data tier whereas any client specific threading issues will be addressed at the client tier.